# Why is sizeof(str) 8 when the string has 26 chars?

Tags: c++

I created the following array:

```
 char* myarr= "data successfully inserted";
```

when I do

```
sizeof(myarr)
```

I get 8. Why do I get that?. If 1 char is 1 byte then size of myarr should be 26 by just counting the characters right?

Comment: Because you are getting the size of the *pointer.* You should have declared it as `char[] myarray = "data successfully inserted";`, which would save 8 bytes of space.

Comment: If the expression `e` has the type `T`, `sizeof(e)` is equivalent to `sizeof(T)`. All objects of a given type have the same size.

Comment: Because you are abusing `sizeof`, and should be using `std::string` first, followed by raw character arrays only if you really need them.

Comment: just do `std::string mystr = "..."` and use `mystr.size()` instead

Comment: "All objects of a given type have the same size". You should write this on a blackboard 100 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your platform, a `char` pointer is 8 bytes. That's the size of the pointer variable, not the size of whatever it's pointing to. If you want the length of a string, call `strlen(myarr)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the size of a pointer on your system. If you want to get the length of a string, you should use `strlen()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(myarr)` is not the size of the string but the size of `char * pointe`r on your platform which gives you `8 bytes`. the size of the array can be calculated by `strlen(myarr)`